# Replacing a class with BCEL

Tags: java, bcel

I'm writing some code where I want to use BCEL to substitute all calls to methods of SomeClass with calls to methods of SomeOtherClass.

Right now, from my understanding, I can do this by:

1. iterating over the instruction list
2. finding all `invokevirtual`, `invokestatic` or `invokespecial` instructions that reference SomeClass
3. replace those with the appropriate invokeX that references SomeOtherClass

This requires me to rewrite a lot of calls tho, and I have to handle at least three different cases (`invokevirtual`, `invokestatic` and `invokespecial` calls).
Instead, is it possible to do it by manipulating the constant pool and replacing all constants that point to SomeClass with SomeOtherClass? if so, how?